# What is the result of a elementary $k$ alternating tensor acting on $k$ different vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I just learn the concept of elementary k form: on an open set $A$. That is if $x\in A$ , then we have   $$\begin{align*}
\phi_I(x)=\phi_{i_1}(x) \wedge  \cdots \wedge \phi_{i_k}(x)
\end{align*}$$ where
$I=(i_1,\ldots ,i_k)$ is an increasing tuple, $\phi_{i_1},\ldots,\phi_{i_k}$ are elementrary 1 form on $A$, and $\phi_{I}$ is a elementary $k$ form on $A$, and hence $\phi_I(x)$ is an alternating $k$ tensor on the tangent space of $x$ denoted as ${\scr T}_x(\mathbb{R}^n)$  . That is $$\begin{align*}
\phi_I(x): {\scr T_x}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}   
\end{align*}$$
Then if I use $(x,v)$ denote vectors in the tangent space of $x$ , I'm wandering what's the result of $$\begin{align*}
\phi_I(x)((x,v_1),\ldots ,(x,v_k))
\end{align*}$$
I think the result is not easy to write out. In other words, for elementary $k$ tensors $$\begin{align*}
\psi_I(v_1,\cdots ,v_k)&= [\phi_{i_1}\cdots \phi_{i_k}](v_1,\cdots ,v_k)\\ &= \phi_{i_1}(v_1)\cdots \phi_{i_k}(v_k) \\ &= v_1^{i_1}\cdots v_k^{i_k}
\end{align*}$$ where $v_1^{i_1}$ is the $i_1$ coordinate of vector $v_1$. But if we have $$\begin{align*}
\phi_{I}(v_1,\cdots ,v_k)
\end{align*}$$ where $\phi_{I}=\phi_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \phi_{i_k}$, I don't think one can get the answer easily, since wedge product involves the sign of permutations. Is this true?

---

Edit:

Here the definition of wedge product is the following:

If we have a vector space $V$ with dimension $n$, and $f$ is a $k$ alternating tensor and $g$ is a $l$ alternating tensor. Then we have there wedge product：  $$\begin{align*}
(f \wedge g)(v_1,\ldots ,v_{k+l})=\sum\limits_{\sigma\in S_{k,l}} \text{sgn } (\sigma) f(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots ,v_{\sigma(k)}) g(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots ,v_{\sigma(k+l)})
\end{align*}$$ where $$\begin{align*}
S_{k,l}=\{\sigma\in S_{k+l}: \sigma(1)<\cdots <\sigma(k);\sigma(k+1)<\cdots <\sigma(k+l)\}
\end{align*}$$ $\sigma$ is a permutation.

This is from "Munkres-Analysis on Manifolds"

Comment: What is you definition of wedge product? Once you make that clear, then this is actually pretty straightforward.

Comment: I added the definition of wedge products in my book. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand\sgn{\mathrm{sgn}}
\newcommand\alt{\mathrm{alt}}
$It helps to unravel the set $S_{k,l}$. Suppose we drop the $\sigma(1) < \dotsb < \sigma(k)$ requirement. This gives a set $S_{[k],l}$ which we can express as
$$
  S_{[k],l} = \{\sigma'\circ\sigma \;:\; \sigma \in S_{k,l},\: \sigma'\in S_{(k),l}\},\quad S_{(k),l} = \{\sigma \in S_{k+l} \;:\; \sigma(i) = i,\: k+1\leq i\leq k+l\}
$$
where $S_{k+l}$ is the set of all permutations on $\{1,\dotsc,k+l\}$. For every $\sigma \in S_{k,l}$ there are $k!$ elements of the form $\sigma'\circ\sigma$ in $S_{[k],l}$, and $|S_{[k],l}| = k!|S_{k,l}|$. Now we note that
$$
  f(v_{\sigma'\circ\sigma(1)},\dotsc,v_{\sigma'\circ\sigma(k)}) = \sgn(\sigma')f(v_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc, v_{\sigma(k)})
$$
and then
$$\begin{aligned}
  (f\wedge g)(v_1,\dotsc,v_{k+l})
    &= \sum_{\sigma\in S_{k,l}}
      \sgn(\sigma)
      f(v_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc,v_{\sigma(k)})g(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\dotsc,v_{\sigma(k+l)})
\\
    &= \frac1{k!}\sum_{\sigma'\in S_{(k),l}}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k,l}}
      \sgn(\sigma')\sgn(\sigma)
      f(v_{\sigma'(\sigma(1))},\dotsc,v_{\sigma'(\sigma(1))})
      g(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\dotsc,v_{\sigma(k+l)})
\\
    &= \frac1{k!}\sum_{\delta\in S_{[k],l}}
      \sgn(\delta)
      f(v_{\delta(1)},\dotsc,v_{\delta(k)})
      g(v_{\delta(k+1)},\dotsc,v_{\delta(k+l)}).
\end{aligned}$$
A similar argument for the $k+1,\dotsc,k+l$ portion yields
$$
  (f\wedge g)(v_1,\dotsc,v_{k+l})
    = \frac1{k!l!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}
      \sgn(\sigma)
      f(v_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc,v_{\sigma(k)})
      g(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\dotsc,v_{\sigma(k+l)}).
$$
Define the tensor product as
$$
  (f\otimes g)(v_1,\dotsc,v_{k+l}) = f(v_1,\dotsc,v_k)g(v_{k+1},\dotsc,v_{k+l})
$$
and the (unnormalized) alternation map for 1-forms $\phi_1,\dotsc,\phi_k$ by
$$
  \alt(\phi_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes\phi_k)
    = \sum_{\sigma\in S_k}
      \sgn(\sigma)\phi_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\dotsb\otimes\phi_{\sigma(k)}
$$
which we extend by linearity to all tensors. Then
$$
  f\wedge g = \frac1{k!l!}\alt(f\otimes g).
$$
By the fact that
$$
  \sgn(\sigma)\alt(\phi_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\dotsb\otimes\phi_{\sigma(k)}) = \alt(\phi_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes\phi_k)
$$
for any $\sigma \in S_k$, we can argue by induction on $k$ that
$$
  \phi_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge\phi_k = \alt(\phi_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes\phi_k).
$$
The RHS applied to $(v_1,\dotsc,v_k)$ is precisely the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}
  \phi_1(v_1) & \phi_1(v_2) & \cdots & \phi_1(v_k) \\
  \phi_2(v_1) & \phi_2(v_2) & \cdots & \phi_2(v_k)\\
  \vdots      & \vdots      & \ddots & \vdots \\
  \phi_k(v_1) & \phi_k(v_2) & \cdots & \phi_k(v_k).
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: Note that this is all done at some fixed point $x \in A$ since this is really about multilinear algebra and the set $A$ is irrelevant.